# Set multiple redirect_uri in the app console

Tags: box-api

There are 2 flows of connecting user box accounts to my box application. Those 2 flows need different domains for a redirect_uri. Is it possible to specify somehow multiple redirect_uri for a box app, so all of them would be valid in the OAuth 2 authorization flow?
Currently I do see an option to add only 1 redirect_uri in the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the setting in app settings empty. Then the API should allow you to supply an address from the application (so you can use two different in different places). It goes as a parameter in the URI you send you user to authenticate, if I remember correctly...